# Unresolved references when testing in another module with testImplementation project(:deepestModule)

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, kotlin

I have a multi-module project setup. When testing, I found that I kept redefining some mocks in each module. So I was hoping to define my mock in the deepest module and reuse it in outer modules

What I did:

1. I put the mock definition into test source set `val mock = Mock(val id: String = "blah")`
2. Adjusted the outer module build file to say `testImplementation project(:deepestModule)`
3. In outer module tests, I reference the mock like so `assertThat(mock.id).isEqualTo("blah")`

No compilation errors, but when I run my outer tests, the build fails with unresolved references to the mock.

Is there a trick to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Test classes in one project are not exposed to other projects, not even the tests of those other projects. This is by design. Unit tests in a project are usually specific to that project and should not leak onto the classpath of anything else.

That being said, there is a legitimate use case for sharing mocks and other test resources. We generally call these *test fixtures* and it looks like this is exactly what you want.

If you are on Gradle 5.6 or later, there is direct support for that. You will have to apply the `java-test-fixtures` plugin and move your Kotlin test sources that define the mocks to `src/testFixtures/kotlin`. The actual unit tests should still reside in the `test` source set. The fixture can then be consumed in other projects with `testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":deepestModule")))`. You can read more about it in the Gradle user guide [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures).

If you are on an older version of Gradle, you will have to separate the test fixtures from the main source code. So in this case you will have to create a new sub-project with your test code. In this project, put the source in the `main` source set and don't use the `test` configurations. Write it like a normal library, even though it is only for tests. Then you can consume it the way you tried already with `testImplementation(project(:deepestModule))`.

By the way, is there a particular reason why you are using the Groovy DSL over the Kotlin DSL? Since you are building a Kotlin project anyway, the latter seems more appropriate.

Comment: Apologies for such a delay. This is just what I needed. Thanks! As for your question, I simply haven't had a chance to learn the Kotlin DSL for Gradle yet. But you are absolutely right, Kotlin for Gradle is more suitable for a Kotlin project.